# I have this problem in option while adding matching quiz in Moodle

Tags: php, html, moodle

I am using the matching quiz and i put option and everything but the option list is not coming properly. I want it like ( i, ii, iii, iv) in the list. And i disabled the shuffle option in editor also so it didn't shuffle my answers. Anyone can please help in this.

[image: moodle matching quiz]

Comment: Options will be shuffled.They cannot come in sequence and shuffle option is for A B C D dropdowns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options will be shuffled.They cannot come in sequence and shuffle option is for A B C D dropdowns refer the moodle docs it is clearly mention there for lesson it is different case